# Reference model from inside serialised object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a model Unit who has a serialised array of Skill objects. Is it then possible to have a method inside the serialised skill object, that references attributes on the Unit model?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is how your model looks like:

```
class Skill
  # has methods that do something meaningful
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base

  serialize :some_attr_name, Skill

end

unit = Unit.first

skill = unit.some_attr_name
```

Now object 'skill' is an instance of class Skill which has no reference to object 'unit' at this point.